# Processing dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary - where the values are dictionaries themselves.
How do I extract the unique set of the values from the child dictionaries in the most efficient way?

```
{ 'A':{'A1':'A1V','B2':'A2V'..},
  'B':{'B1':'B1V','B2':'B2V'...},
  ...}
```

Expected output:

```
['A1V','A2V','B1V','B2V'...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a single line:

```
>>> [val for dct in x.values() for val in dct.values()]
['A1V', 'A2V', 'B2V', 'B1V']
```

Assuming you named your dict of dict `x`.

You mentioned unique, in that case replace the list-comprehension by a set-comprehension:

```
>>> {val for dct in x.values() for val in dct.values()}  # curly braces!
{'A1V', 'A2V', 'B1V', 'B2V'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
uniques = set()
for ukey, uvalue in outerdic.items():
    for lkey, lvalue in uvalue.items():
        uniques.add(lvalue)
print uniques
```

Using a set should work. New to stackoverflow, trying to figure out how syntax highlighting works.

This assumes that the dictionary is called outerdic.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = { 'A':{'A1':'A1V','B2':'A2V'},'B':{'B1':'B1V','B2':'B2V'}}

for key in dictionary.keys() :
    dict1 = dictionary[key]
    for key1 in dict1.keys():
        print(dict1[key1])
```

Tried to keep it as simple as possible.